# failed to find PDF header: '%PDF' not found

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, ipad

I am trying to download pdf content from webservice endpoint which is coming as binary. After decoding into base64 I am attaching the decoded file to webview, in which failed to find pdf header error is displaying.

Does anyone know how can I proceed to fix this error? Am I missing any step here?

Thanks.

Comment: What does your code look like? That error most likely comes up if the PDF does not exist or cannot

Comment: mwinn22, I am using Base64 class from http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/04/20/encrypting-decrypting-base64-encode-decode-in-iphone-objective-c/   and just decoding the value from array and storing in nsdata.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding something like

```
NSData *dataContent; // response data.
CFDataRef myPDFData;
myPDFData = (CFDataRef)dataContent;
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(myPDFData);

pdfDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(provider);

CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
```

Then load pdfDocument into your webview.

or have a look at making a custom zoomPDFViewer. Apple have a good example at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html thats what I did as I couldn't get the pdfdocument to load correctly in a webview.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error when developing my app that read pdf's the issue is the PDF doesn't exist at where your calling it from. The binary data that is being returned is the error response that your web service is calling. For example if I am requesting a pdf document at :

http://localhost:8080/template/DocumentServlet?documentId=923447&JSSESIONID=77EFJD3IJD8I3MMWW2435353J

if that document doesn't exist at that address then I will get an error response, and that is what the binary data is that is being returned.

Comment: matt, I can see the data is being downloaded and parsed into nsdata, maybe it might be possible that I wasn't decoding properly, now I don't have that error but it doesn't shows anything on the pdf. Just grey pdf, and I did write to pdf and tried to open pdf, yet it gives me an error the pdf file is damaged.

Comment: @kforkarim: He's not saying that there isn't data, he's saying that the data is the error response, not the PDF you tried to get. Make sure that the URL you're trying to access is the correct URL and that the resource exists and is accessible (you have permission, it's reachable, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution if you use the SAP web service:
in SAP System there is a method to convert the binary data (XSTRING) to Base64:
cl_http_utility=>encode_x_base64
Using http it is possible to transfer the Base64 data.
In xcode I used this library:
[a link](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/04/20/encrypting-decrypting-base64-encode-decode-in-iphone-objective-c/)

```
// 3) Decode Base 64
// Then you can put that back like this
NSData  *b64DecData = [Base64 decode:b64EncStr];
```

then:`[webDisplay loadData:b64DecData MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];`