# failed to find PDF header: '%PDF' not found in xCode

Tags: xcode, pdf-generation

I'm trying to create a PDF Object from binary xString in xCode. (OData from SAP, utf-8)

Here is the coding:

```
const char* buf = [temp1 UTF8String];
pdffile = [NSData dataWithBytes:buf length:length1];
[webDisplay loadData:self.pdffile MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
self.webDisplay.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

temp1 is a XString
length1 is the length of PDF file in bytes.

I get following error message:

failed to find PDF header: '%PDF' not found

Some ideas?

Comment: what does buf look like? Is it valid PDF. Look at the first few bytes, do you see the %PDF there?

Comment: unfortunately there is no %PDF String. buf begins with: 255044462D312E350D0A25B5B5B5B50D0A312030206F626A0D0A3C3C2F547970652F436174616C6F67

Comment: That is correct, 25=%, 50=P and so on. I'm not sure why it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my incorrect deleted answer you said:

> I use two SAP standard function modules to create from PDF a XString:
>   SCMS_AO_TABLE_GET_BYTES and SCMS_BINARY_TO_XSTRING –

When you say you have 2550, do you a 2, then a 5 etc... or do you mean 0x25. Hex 25 is what you want, if you have an ascii 2 then an ascii5 that will certainly not work. Examine the memory in the debugger.

Comment: Hi Paul, sap function module SCMS_BINARY_TO_XSTRING creates the xstring in binary mode and provides the length1 of the pdf file. The real length of the xstring = length1 * 2. So I think it is correct.

Comment: The only way to be certain is to examine the memory in the debugger.

Comment: here are following values from debugger: temp1: [link](http://www.file-upload.net/download-4181406/temp1.rtf.html)   ; pdffile: [link](http://www.file-upload.net/download-4181404/pdffile.rtf.html); buf is unfortunately not available: (gdb) po buf
0xa075000 does not appear to point to a valid object.

Comment: That's your problem! In pdffile.rft you have 32353530, 32 is an ascii 2, 35 is an ascii 5 so instead of 0x25, a "%" as the first character in your buffer, you have 0x35, which is a "2" You need to send the correct binary data to dataWithBytes. UTF8String is the wrong call, that is giving you a string.

Comment: How can I convert the string Data to binary data in the correct way?

Comment: Beats me, that is a SAP library function. You all to do some research on that. But try this, just don't call UTF8String, pass temp1 directly to dateWithBytes?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work... Here is the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857310/failed-to-find-pdf-header-pdf-not-found/9604547#9604547 but how can I contact the person who asked the question? May be he could solve the problem?

Comment: I still have no solution for my problem...

Comment: You need to research your SAP library. You answer lies in there. Guaranteed.

Answer (score 2):

here is the solution:
in SAP System there is a method to convert the binary data (XSTRING) to Base64:
cl_http_utility=>encode_x_base64
Using http it is possible to transfer the Base64 data.
In xcode I used this library:
[a link](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/04/20/encrypting-decrypting-base64-encode-decode-in-iphone-objective-c/)

```
// 3) Decode Base 64
// Then you can put that back like this
NSData  *b64DecData = [Base64 decode:b64EncStr];
```

then:`[webDisplay loadData:b64DecData MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];`